# Reading serial: also receiving characters I am sending

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-uno

I am communicating through Serial2 (arduino mega) by sending and receiving text.

95% of the time the communication goes well, but some of the text I am reading contains also parts of the text I am sending.

Code:

```
void setup (){
  Serial.begin (19200);
  while (!Serial) {
  }
  Serial1.begin(19200);
  Serial2.begin (19200);
}

void loop (){
  currentMillis = millis();
  if(currentMillis > savedMillis + 1000){ 
    Serial2.write("@@geenbatterij##\r\n"); //check batterij
    Serial2.write("@@geensignaal##\r\n");
    savedMillis = millis();
  }
 SerialEvent2zelf();
}

void serialEvent2zelf(){
  if(Serial2.available()>0){
    while (Serial2.available()){
      processIncomingByte(Serial2.read ());
    }
  }
}

void processIncomingByte (const byte inByte){
  static char input_line [MAX_INPUT];
  static unsigned int input_pos = 0;
  switch (inByte){
    case '#':   // end of text
      input_line [input_pos] = 0;  // terminating null byte
      process_data (input_line);
      input_pos = 0;  
      startSignReceived = false;
      break;
  //  case '\r':   // discard carriage return
  //    break;
    case '@':   // begin of text
      startSignReceived = true;
      break;
    default:
      if (input_pos < (MAX_INPUT - 1) && startSignReceived == true)
        input_line [input_pos++] = inByte;
      break;
    }  
  }
```

Output (console reading):

```
odr/3.8
rnt/102h6m
as1/28.9
as2/28.8
ls1/0.1
ls2/0.1
bsn/82
kwt/74
wd1/4.7
wd2/0.7
rnt/102h6m
rpm/972
odr/3.7
rnt/102herijrnt/signaalrnt/102h6m   //<-- see here
as1/28.9
as2/28.8
ls1/0.1
ls2/0.1
bsn/82
kwt/74
wd1/4.7
wd2/0.7
rnt/102h6m
rpm/981
odr/3.8
rnt/102h6m
as1/28.9
as2/28.8
ls1/0.1
ls2/0.1
```

What am I doing wrong and how to solve it? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think the problem can be reproduced. Spontaneously it sounds as if you are executing some processing code without waiting for the rx flag, or the rx flag is not properly cleared in some cases. You should add code to handle the case where no `#` has been spotted but you reached MAX_INPUT. One thing you could try for debugging purposes is to clear all the contents of `input_line` between transmissions and see if the problem persists (hw/communication bug) or goes away (software/design bug).

Comment: @Lundin Thank you, this will skip the corrupt readings. But I need to know how those corrupt reading occur so I can prevent it. How come a part of what I am sending gets in between the text I am receiving?

Comment: If clearing the buffer fixed the problem, then you have a bug somewhere... and not necessarily in the code you have posted.

Comment: @Lundin What do you mean by clearing the buffer? can you give me an example?

Comment: @Lundin I mean the Rx & Tx are 2 different lines, how can they mess up?

Comment: Reading 2 sentences: I say buffer overflow or missing NUL terminations

Comment: @sehe: Any advice on how to solve? I already increased Serial buffer size from 64 to 256 bytes.

Comment: Re "Rx & Tx are 2 different lines": you are not handling 'the lines". You are handling buffers. You don't need the lines to mess up if you mess up the buffer.

Comment: @sehe Thank you, do you notice anything incorrect from the code I posted?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you have multiple instances of the `Serial` class is more than a little suspect because I am pretty sure you're only using a single serial port.

I'd suggest using only the first instance and completely removing `serial1` and `serial2`.

Other notes :

- code is missing. It could very well contain Undefined Behaviour
- Maar weinig mensen lezen hier Nederlands. Het is niet de conventie om Nederlands te mengen met code